# Python regex sub multiple times

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to get multiple times words inside html tags.
For instace like this:

```
<title>GateUser UserGate</title>
```

I want to cath both 'GateUser' and 'UserGate'
I'm using the next regexp:

```
re.sub(ur'(<.*>.*)(\b\w{8}\b)(.*</.*>)', r'\1\g<2>ADDED\3', html)
```

I would like to replace any word inside html tag that matche this  `\b\w{8}\b` condition, re.sub allows only one.

Comment: Hand `re.sub` a fourth parameter: `re.GLOBAL`.

Comment: not clear, can you please elaborate a bit? do you want to replace both words, or anything inside the tag ?

Comment: Regex and html don't go well together ([obligatory link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)). Why don't you use a html parser to get the text content of the tag, then modify only that?

Comment: Thou shall not use regex to parse HTML

Answer (score 1):

Using `re` for parsing HTML not really needed as you do have many brilliantly written libraries for that, But still One way you can achieve what you want by:

- parsing tags.
- change their innerHtml.

Lets say you have some html:

```
a = """
  <title>GateUser UserGate</title>
  <div style="something">
    KameHame Ha
  </div>
  """
```

Now you can relatively easily parse the tags including the innerHtml:

```
blanks = r"([\s\n\t]+?)"   # totally optional depending on code indentation and stuff.
pat = re.compile(r"(<.+>){0}(.*?){0}(</.+>)".format(blanks))

# tuples don't support item assignment, so mapping list, but still tuples fine too.
tags_with_inner = list(map(list, pat.findall(a)))

# [ ['<title>', '', 'GateUser UserGate', '', '</title>'],
# ['<div style="something">', '\n    ', 'KameHame Ha', '\n  ', '</div>']]
```

And then match your `regex` on the inner only:

```
only_inner = re.compile(r"\b\w{8}\b")  # your expression

for inner in tags_with_inner:
  inner[2] = only_inner.sub("ADDED", inner[2])
  print ("".join(inner))

# <title>ADDED ADDED</title>
# <div style="something">
#     ADDED Ha
#   </div>
```

Comment: Ok. How can I get original html but with replaced things? This is main thing that wories me

Comment: well its better to use html/xml parser modules for that, ou are just making things difficult for you. Try the module `lxml` on pypi, Its pretty descent.